# Loop Copy Cell that contains Formula Paste in Same Cell as Value

Tags: excel, vba

Coming here because i am struggling a bit with VBA looping.

Requesting some assistance for code to handle the below situation:

I have multiple columns (have named ranges for each) that have formulas in a data table. I want to reduce the file size size since keeping all of the formulas exponentially increases the file size as more records are entered into the data structure. I have approximately 135 columns that are formulated.

Step 1 - I need to copy cells in a multiple columns to be copied and pasted as a value in the same cell. Except for the first row of data which that would always contain the formulas.

Step 2 - Macro to Reinsert the formulas to update the records from the first row.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Luckily loops are not needed.  This is for column **B** only.  This routine converts all the cells except **B1** from formulas to values:

```
Sub column2values()
    Dim B1 As Range, B2N As Range, N As Long

    Set B1 = Range("B1")
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set B2N = Range("B2:B" & N)

    With B2N
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

and this sub takes the formula still remaining in **B1** and copies it downward:

```
Sub restoreFormulas()
    Dim B1 As Range, B2N As Range, N As Long

    Set B1 = Range("B1")
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set B2N = Range("B2:B" & N)

    B1.Copy B2N
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the response. This works but in my situation with so many columns I have to do this for was why i why i think i would need some sort of loop. Referencing 130 columns individually is not ideal.